# Can't install gem using Bundler's Rakefile install task when developing a custom gem

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rvm, bundler, gem-bundler

I'm developing a couple of private gems and I think I don't understand correctly the PATH/GEM_PATH and/or Bundler/RVM installation flow, would love if someone could chip in.

I have a repository with two gems (A & B for simplicity sake). I've developed the gems using the scaffolding + following the guidelines provided by [this bundler tutorial](http://bundler.io/v1.15/guides/creating_gem.html#getting-started).

Thanks to the Bundler project I have a few Rakefile tasks like `rake build`, `rake install`, `rake install:local` and `rake release`. Because of the private nature of these gems I can't release them to RubyGems (and we haven't looked into hosting our rubygems).

My machines are using RVM to manage ruby versions and Bundler version 1.15.1

**What I want to do:** Assuming a new machine/developer trying out the project, ideally we would `cd` into each of the subfolders (currently 2, gem A and gem B), run `rake install` and after that we should have the gems available system wide for the current user.

**What is happening:** The gems are built and work properly, but they are only available inside the subfolder of each gem i.e. gem A is only available inside the subfolder A and gem B is only available inside subfolder B.

**What I've tried:** So, after `rake build/install/install:local` a new `.gem` file is generated under `pkg`. I've tried to manually install the "compiled" file using `gem install pkg/A.gem`, `gem install --local pkg/A.gem` and `gem install --local --user-install pkg/A.gem` without success. ([there are plenty of SO questions/answers about this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31596273/install-gem-in-local-folder))

I believe this has something to do with the PATH variables, but like I said before I don't fully understand the way they are managed. I get the following results from these commands:

```
# Our gem
> gem which A
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/A-0.1.8/lib/A.rb

# Pry, available globally
> gem which pry
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/pry-0.11.1/lib/pry.rb
```

I've been lost and frustrated for far too long now, any help is appreciated. Also open to hear suggestions of better private gem installation flows :)

Comment: Try installing your gem to the global gemset with `rvm @global do gem install --local pkg/A.gem`

Comment: Didn't fixed it for me. I ran `rvm @global do gem install pkg/A-0.1.8.gem` and now `gem which A` prints `/home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/bin/gem`. The installed gems continue to work only inside each directory. Even tried running from the repo's root dir the following (without success): `rvm @global do gem install A/pkg/A-0.1.8.gem`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it has something to do with your PATH variables. Your installation seems to be good.

I advise you to first affirm your gems installation path with:

```
echo $GEM_HOME
```

The double check your PATH to ensure its present and also confirm that the GEM home is also where the gem got installed into from the `rake install`

```
echo $PATH
```

If not, put it in your path and you should be fine with something like this:

```
echo PATH=$PATH:$GEM_HOME >> ~/.bashrc
source ~/.bashrc
```

Answer (score 1):

Build your gem as per that guide you linked. You should end up with a gem file. Distribute this as you see fit (I use rsync/crontab to download newer gem versions but anything goes). User can install the gem as follows:

```
gem install --user-install /path/to/your/file.gem
```

This will install the gem in the user's `~/.gem/ruby/<version>/gems/<your-gem-name>` directory.

Tried it with an empty gem (foodie, as in that example guide) and it works fine. But if you don't specify the --user-install parameter it will try to install in the system ruby dir (/usr/lib/ruby/gems...)